# how to return a variable to the main class from anot main class

Tags: java

So I just learnt today how to make a secondary class take into account a variable from the main class.

But how do I do the reverse that is a variable with a value in the secondary class have that same value in the main class?

here the code:

```
package maiN;

public class nintodec {
    public static void convertToDec(String number) {
        number = new StringBuffer(number).reverse().toString();
        int numero = 0;
        int mult = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++) {
            int digit = number.charAt(i);
            digit = Character.getNumericValue(digit);
            numero = numero + (mult * digit);
            mult = mult * 9;
        }
    }
}
```

as you can see numero is calculated in the secondary class and i want the value returned to this main class:

```
package maiN;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class director {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter a base nine number");
        String number = keyboard.next();
        nintodec.convertToDec(number);
        System.out.println(numero); // here numero is not recognized for is from
                                    // the other class
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of return void, why don't you return a number?

Comment: Please format your code properly. Indentation makes your code easier to read and spot potential problems.

Comment: Also please use java naming conventions. Classes names should start with upper-case (I edited your examples to add proper indentation but you need to work on naming convention).

Comment: `String`s are _immutable_ in Java, which is why `nintodec.convertToDec(number);` does not change the value of  `number` to anything.

Comment: @MickMnemonic I do not see how it is gonna be an issue here. can you explain better?

Comment: @KickButtowski, sorry, my bad, I read the `System.out` to have `number` in it (and assumed the OP posted code that compiles).

Comment: @MickMnemonic never be sorry about anything. you raised a valid and good questions. I was just asking ;)

Answer (score 1):

you want to make `convertToDec()` return an `int`, so change the `void` you have there to `int`. Then you will want to add `return numero;` to the end of your `convertToDec` method.

This will make it so that int will get passed back and you can use it later.

then in main you want to do

```
//other code..
String number=keyboard.next();
int numero = nintodec.convertToDec(number);  
System.out.println(numero)
```

Also, please try reading & learning about some of Java's standards in terms of naming and the like, it will make your code much easier to maintain and read in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is about **`variable scope`** ,and you can rectify that with following.

You have two options:

1. Print out the value inside the `convertToDec` if you are done with your calculation, as a result, `numero` variable no need to be visible there in order to be printed.
2. Instead of return `void`, you should return `int` so you can use it for further calculation inside `director` class

your function signature change from

```
public  static void convertToDec(String number){
```

to

```
public  static int convertToDec(String number){
```

**Note**: do not forget to use `return numero` in your function.

When you return a type `int` , the value of `numero` variable can be visible to your secondary class so you expand its scope